# Sitecore Forms - Incorrect form submission redirection

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have a basic form built in Sitecore Forms. One of the fields is marked as mandatory. If a user submits the form without having input a value in the mandatory field, they are redirected to a page displaying only the form elements and no CSS. Is there an OOTB function I can use to deny a user's submission if they have not addressed the 'mandatory' fields?

Comment: Sounds like you did not include the Html Helpers to add Form Scripts and Styles. You need to add these for the validation. Make sure you [follow the instructions from the documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/setting_up_and_configuring/add_a_form_to_a_web_page).

Comment: what version of sitecore are you using? If you're using sitecore 9 with Ajax enabled, there was an issue. This link might help. https://citizensitecore.com/2017/12/13/sitecore-9-forms-and-ajax-with-sxa/

Comment: I'm using Sitecore 9 Update 1; the issue was that I hadn't included the @Html.RenderFormStyles() and @Html.RenderFormScripts() in the outer layout